# Migrate Google+ photos to Google Photos and free up Data Quota

Tags: google-plus-photos, google-photos

I see my old Photos that were uploaded to google+ in the new photos app.  I have it set for the new free high resolution, but I still see google+ photos taking up 7 gbs when I go to drive and check my quota.
Can I delete the photos from google+ or should I try something else first?
I would prefer not to lose my old photos. I would think they would be moved to the new free storage because they are all smaller than the 16MP limit for the high resolution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google hasn't announced anything about moving these. While it's possible, if not likely, that they may do so at some point, your only sure-fire solution would be to download all your photos, delete them from Google Photos, and then re-upload them under the new setting.